# How to add an option to jsTree context menu

Tags: jstree

Can somebody help me.  I don't understand the documentation of jsTree well enough to achieve what I am trying to do.

I want to add an option to jsTree's context menu, so this is what I have done:

```
$(function () {
    $('#jstree').jstree({
        "plugins" : [
            "contextmenu",
            "dnd",
            "changed"
            ],

        "core" : {
            "check_callback" : true
        },

        "dnd" : {
            "use_html5" : true
        },
        "contextmenu" : {
            "items" : function(node) {
                var tmp = $.jstree.defaults.contextmenu.items();
                tmp.details = {};
                tmp.details.label = "Details";
                tmp.action = function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    };

                return tmp;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

But this adds two options to the context menu, namely "Details" and "undefined".  Selecting either of these two options does not do the console.log(data); that I was hoping for.

What am I doing wrong?  How do I get just one item added (ie. remove the undefined) and how do I make it do something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duh - just seen my mistake:

```
tmp.action = function(data) {
```

should be:

```
tmp.details.action = function(data) {
```